# google sheets api select non-adjacent cells

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

What would be the range for selecting multiple non-adjacent cells?

I am trying to update cells that are non-adjacent from a sheet (A2 and A5). I know how to update contiguous cells: 'SheetName'!A2:5, but how can I update only cell 2 and 5. I am using python:

```
    sheetRange = str("'Telegram'!A2:5")
    value_range = [['a'],['False'],['True']]
    value_range = {
        "values": value_range,
    }
    request = self.service.spreadsheets().values().update(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetid, range=sheetRange,
                                                          valueInputOption="RAW",
                                                          body=value_range )
    response = self.requestExecute(request)
    return response
```

Comment: Did my answer work? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same problem with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved.

Answer (score 1):

How about using sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate? By using sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate, you can update each cell like "A2" and "A5". Following sample script is from [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). You can see the request body from this script.

**Please be careful that in this case, [GridRange](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange) instead of [a1Notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation) is used for the coordinate of cells.**

#### Sample script :

This sample script supposes that you have already been ready to use Sheets API v4.

```
batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body = {
    "requests":
    [
        {
            "updateCells":
            {
                "range":
                {
                    "sheetId": #####, # Please input your sheetId.
                    "startRowIndex": 1,
                    "endRowIndex": 2,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "rows":
                [
                    {
                        "values":
                        [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue":
                                {
                                    "stringValue": "sample value for A2"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "*"
            }
        },
        {
            "updateCells":
            {
                "range":
                {
                    "sheetId": #####,  # Please input your sheetId.
                    "startRowIndex": 4,
                    "endRowIndex": 5,
                    "startColumnIndex": 0,
                    "endColumnIndex": 1
                },
                "rows":
                [
                    {
                        "values":
                        [
                            {
                                "userEnteredValue":
                                {
                                    "stringValue": "sample value for A5"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "fields": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
request = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=batch_update_spreadsheet_request_body)
response = request.execute()
print(response)
```

#### Reference :

- The detail information of sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate is [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate). You can also see the sample script here.
- GridRange : https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange
- a1Notation : https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.